# Is an iOS app only fully active once it appears in Search?

Tags: ios, itunes

I can download it through the iTunes link but some features like In app purchases are not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

what type error does it give? if inapp purchase not working I recommend you to check your product ids in your app.

Comment: Thanks, we have a suspicion it is because the application has not propogated fully into the iTunes store and therefore the live servers have not picked up the IAP's. Just to be clear, apple have approved the app and all the IAP's and they were all working in testing sandbox.

Comment: You are welcome. I see. Did you forget to submit your products? After creating your product on itunesconnect you should summit them. maybe thats why its working on sandbox.

Comment: In the initial version we had forgot to submit screenshots of the In app purchases, we since altered this and re-submitted and it got approved. I think (hope) now there's just a waiting period for the purchases to go live.

Comment: Yes there is wating period for purchases. Check inapp purchase status in itunesconnect. Select your app and click manage your manage in app purchahes. last column is for status

Answer (score 0):

Right, The in-app purchases took around 24 hours to go live but are now working!

Just to be clear, once you're app is ready for sale there is still a period where In-app purchases will not work.